# What does "draw in crude oil inventories" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Oil Plunges After API Reports Large Unexpected Crude Inventory Build | OilPrice.com](https://oilprice.com/Latest-Energy-News/World-News/Oil-Plunges-After-API-Reports-Large-Unexpected-Crude-Inventory-Build.html)

> The American Petroleum Institute (API) estimated on Tuesday a large crude oil inventory build, of 8.731 million barrels for the week ending May 22.
>
> Analysts had predicted an inventory draw of [2.50 million barrels](https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/eia-crude-oil-inventories-75).
>
> In the previous week, the API estimated a **draw in crude oil inventories** of [4.8 million barrels](https://oilprice.com/Latest-Energy-News/World-News/Oil-Jumps-After-API-Reports-Draw-In-Crude-Oil-Inventories.html). Meanwhile, the EIA’s estimates were for wildly different, with the industry body reporting last week that the inventories had fallen by [5 million barrels](https://oilprice.com/Energy/Crude-Oil/Oil-Soars-On-Bullish-EIA-Inventory-Report.html).

[Oil drops as surprise U.S. stock build douses demand recovery hopes](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/05/28/oil-markets-crude-inventories-coronavirus-in-focus.html)

> Data from U.S. industry group API showed crude stocks rose by 8.7 million barrels in the week to May 22, compared with analysts’ expectations for a **draw** of 1.9 million barrels.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/draw) lists 7 definitions for DRAW as noun, but which here?

Comment: The meaning can be inferred from the context, especially when you’ve got dictionary alternatives.

Comment: @Xanne I'm only guessing, but "On August 21, the DOE reported a decrease in crude oil inventories of 1.4 million barrels. In contrast, analysts actually expected a crude oil inventory draw of 1.5 million barrels. The smaller-than-expected decrease in inventories ..." [[Ingrid Pan, Yahoo Finances](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/lower-expected-inventory-draw-means-163832896.html) seems to suggest that 'inventory draw' means 'decrease in reserves at the specified repository'. I can't find a dictionary definition to match. Of course, 'withdrawal' corresponds, but I'm unfamiliar with this jargon.

Comment: The link the OP provides from Lexico has at def. 3 “Take or obtain (liquid) from a container or receptacle.“     Inventories and reserves are not the same in the oil world, but the two words often have different meanings.  In the answer that got deleted it was stated that the earth is the container from which the draw is made, which is pure invention.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth . . . The Lexico 3 def should be enough to come to a conclusion about the phrase “the draw in crude oil inventories.”

Comment: @EdwinAshworth https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/113015/why-it-important-follow-crude-oil-inventories.asp provides more information.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The Pan article you cite says “ On August 21, the DOE reported a decrease in crude oil inventories of 1.4 million barrels. In contrast, analysts actually expected a crude oil inventory draw of 1.5 million barrels. The smaller-than-expected decrease in inventories was a negative signal for oil prices. WTI closed down on the day at $103.85 per barrel compared to $104.96 per barrel the prior day.“ (Nothing about reserves or a specific location,)

Comment: To your point, @EdwinAshworth, I cannot find “draw” as a noun, except in actual use, in a dictionary, but drawdown is a clearly defined noun .viz https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/draw%20down That’s probably the source, through shortening.

Comment: @Xanne But 'draw **in** U.S. inventories' is markedly different from 'piping _from_' or 'withdrawal _from_.  It behaves far more like 'managed decrease in'. This behaviour is by no means clear in the dictionaries mentioned. Though it may well be a transferred usage, as you say from 'drawdown', 'depletion'.